# Некорректное перетаскивание элемента

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Есть сетка их элементов. 2 из них можно перетаскивать на различные ячейки сетки. Перетаскивание реализовано для телефона, но работает оно не очень корректно.Когда я хватаю элемент за разные места,то он мгновенно перемещается лишь к одному углу,и за этот угол я его и перемещаю.Но правильно было бы,если бы элемент перемещался именно за то место,за которое я его схватил.

[image: хватаю элемент здесь] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:
HTML

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="empty">
    <div class="drag"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
    <div class="drag"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
*,
  ::before,
  ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #234b69;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  outline: 1px solid gold;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.empty {
  height:127px;
  width:81px;
  background:url('https://i.ibb.co/M5LTBcQ/1.png');
  background-size: cover;
  float:left;
  margin:8px;
}

.drag {
  position: absolute;
  height:127px;
  width:81px;
  background:url('https://i.ibb.co/6bz8z8F/1.png');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

.active {
  /* background-color: green; */
}
```

JS

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const empty = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.empty'));
const drag = document.querySelectorAll('.drag');

drag.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);
    element.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);
});


let itemAppend;

function touchMove(event) {
    let drag = event.path[0]
    event.preventDefault();

    let touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    drag.style.top = `${touch.pageY - (wrapper.offsetTop) - (drag.offsetWidth /2)}px`;
    drag.style.left = `${touch.pageX - (wrapper.offsetLeft) - (drag.offsetHeight /2)}px`;

    empty.map(item => {
        if (
            drag.getBoundingClientRect().top + drag.offsetWidth / 2 < item.getBoundingClientRect().bottom &&
            drag.getBoundingClientRect().right - drag.offsetWidth / 2 > item.getBoundingClientRect().left &&
            drag.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - drag.offsetWidth / 2 > item.getBoundingClientRect().top &&
            drag.getBoundingClientRect().left + drag.offsetWidth / 2 < item.getBoundingClientRect().right
        ) {
            item.classList.add('active');
            itemAppend = item;
        }
        else {
            item.classList.remove('active');
        }
    });
}


function touchEnd(element) {
    if (itemAppend.classList.contains('active')) {
        itemAppend.append(this);
        this.style.top = `${itemAppend.offsetTop}px`;
        this.style.left = `${itemAppend.offsetLeft}px`;
    }
    else {
        this.style.top = `${itemAppend.offsetTop}px`;
        this.style.left = `${itemAppend.offsetLeft}px`;
    }
}
```

Скорее всего надо исправить условие:

```
drag.style.top = `${touch.pageY - (wrapper.offsetTop) - (drag.offsetWidth /2)}px`;
drag.style.left = `${touch.pageX - (wrapper.offsetLeft) - (drag.offsetHeight /2)}px`;
```

Но не могу понять,как правильно написать выражение,используя координаты

Comment: О, у меня сын играл в эту игру! Приложите сюда минимальный воспроизводимый пример - поправлю.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , я приложил ссылку на codepan,там ничего лишнего: [https://codepen.io/stepashka20/pen/mdmKeoq](https://codepen.io/stepashka20/pen/mdmKeoq)
На 20-21 строках как раз и находится вычисление координат

Comment: Дело в том, что СО - не только для помощи вам. Это еще и база знаний. Вы можете изменить codepen, пофиксить баг и тогда ваш вопрос станет бесполезным для сообщества. Поэтому требуется вставлять код непосредственно в вопрос!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ,а,хорошо,я просто специально этот pen оставил и не редактирую,но сейчас код вставлю

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ,исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку `touch` события не подедрживают `offsetX/Y` относительно элемента, приходится вручную вычислять offset при `touchstart`.

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const empty = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.empty'));
const drag = document.querySelectorAll('.drag');

drag.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
  element.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);
  element.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);
});


let itemAppend;
let offsetY = 0;
let offsetX = 0;

function touchStart(event) {
  let drag = event.path[0]
  const touch = event.targetTouches[0];
  // высчитваем и запоминаем разницу между верхней гранью контейнера и верхней гранью перетаскиваемого элемента
  offsetY = touch.pageY - drag.offsetTop;
  offsetX = touch.pageX - drag.offsetLeft;
}

function touchMove(event) {
  let drag = event.path[0]
  event.preventDefault();
  let touch = event.targetTouches[0];
  drag.style.top = `${touch.pageY - offsetY}px`;
  drag.style.left = `${touch.pageX - offsetX}px`;

  empty.map(item => {
    if (
      drag.getBoundingClientRect().top + drag.offsetWidth / 2 < item.getBoundingClientRect().bottom &&
      drag.getBoundingClientRect().right - drag.offsetWidth / 2 > item.getBoundingClientRect().left &&
      drag.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - drag.offsetWidth / 2 > item.getBoundingClientRect().top &&
      drag.getBoundingClientRect().left + drag.offsetWidth / 2 < item.getBoundingClientRect().right
    ) {
      item.classList.add('active');
      itemAppend = item;
    } else {
      item.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
}


function touchEnd(element) {
  if (itemAppend.classList.contains('active')) {
    itemAppend.append(this);
    this.style.top = `${itemAppend.offsetTop}px`;
    this.style.left = `${itemAppend.offsetLeft}px`;
  } else {
    this.style.top = `${itemAppend.offsetTop}px`;
    this.style.left = `${itemAppend.offsetLeft}px`;
  }
}
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #234b69;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  outline: 1px solid gold;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.empty {
  height: 127px;
  width: 81px;
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/M5LTBcQ/1.png');
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
}

.drag {
  position: absolute;
  height: 127px;
  width: 81px;
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/6bz8z8F/1.png');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

.active {
  /* background-color: green; */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="empty">
    <div class="drag" draggable></div>
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
    <div class="drag" draggable></div>
  </div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
</div>
```